# Configuring flake8 line length with null-ls in neovim

Tags: neovim, plugin-null-ls

I would like to change the default line length flake8 uses from 79 to 88. I've setup flake8 with null-ls, but it isn't clear how to change the options for flake8 within the lua file.

I've found examples to set options for black by including similar to `null-ls.builtins.formatting.black.with({extra_args = {"--line-length 100"}})` and I've tried `null-ls.builtins.diagnostics.flake8.with({extra_args = {"--max-line-length 88"}})` without success.

I have finally caved and put a `.flake8` file in the directory, which works, but I'd like to have it all in my config file if possible.

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Realized that multiple items need to be separated by a comma, meaning the correct code is `….bultins.diagnostics.flake8.with({extra_args = {"--max-line-length","88"}})`